# Spring security context and @Repository bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it safe to access to the Spring Security context from `@Repository` bean?

Let us say that we have some `@Repository`:

```
public interface FooRep {
    Foo getFoo();
}

@Repository
public class FooRepImpl {    
    public Foo getFoo() {
       Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       return (Foo)authentication.getDetails();
    }
}
```

It is wrapped into service layer:

```
public interface FooService {
     Foo getFoo();
}

@Service    
public class FooServiceImpl {
    @Autowired FooRep fooRep;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return fooRep.getFoo();
    }
}
```

And let us say that this method is accessed from secured controller, something like that:

```
@RestController
@Secured
public void FooController {
     @Autowired FooService fooSer;

     @RequestMapping("/foo");
     public Foo getFoo() {
         return fooSer.getFoo();
     }
}
```

This is very simplified example, but essential part of logic is here.

**Please, do not ask me why do I need it and do not give me advices how to restructure this architecture.**

I only need to know, can it cause any issues related to multithread usage?

The question is arisen, because we have experienced cases when `authentication.getDetails()` contained `Foo` instance different from that which was placed there in the authentication interceptor. This is very weird and looks impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a case when you start e.g. a Job which has no access to Request so don't have access to auth info but the Job still uses the repository.

If you create a new thread and access the repository from the thread again could be an issue.

Comment: Excuse me, how does the scenario you have described coincide with the scenario which I have provided (Controller -> Service -> Repository)?

Comment: In the simple case it's fine but you asked about multithreading. I described potential problems. In general is better to keep layers so you can get the auth from controller and pass to service and deeper to repository as a parameter rather than direct access.